# Understanding C# Delegates Structure

Tags: c#, delegates

I've been trying to understand C# delegates using [Pro C# 5](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1430242337).

In short, the author describes the motivation for delegates as a structured way of dealing with function pointers and callbacks or two-way communication between objects.

The part I find confusing is the syntax/implementation for this:

- On the one hand, an object of delegate type is seen as the *handler*
  or the one responsible for invoking some method or list of methods. To this end, it has
  methods such as `Invoke()` etc.
- On the other hand, the delegate type is used as a 'wrapper' with
  which to pass around methods.

For example, it seems strange to me that a call to a delegate's `GetInvocationList()` returns an array of delegates. Shouldn't there be something else with which to wrap methods?

I expected there would be some other construct/type, say, `MethodContainer` which wraps methods. Then the syntax for adding methods to a delegate would be

```
class MyClass{ void Method(string s){} }

MyClass c = new MyClass();
MethodContainer container = new MethodContainer(c.Method);

delegate void MyDelegate(string s);
MyDelegate d = new MyDelegate();

d.Add(container);

d.GetInvocationList(); // returns array of MethodContainer
```

Comment: This isn't very clear. What sort of "something else" could there be? How would it be different? .NET delegates' design is largely tied into events, where you have a chain of functions to call when some event  occurs.

Comment: For example it wouldn't have methods such as `Invoke`.

Comment: What is it you want to know exactly about delegates, the way they're working, or how to work with them? It's unclear to me what you're asking.

Comment: Could you give an example of the code that you find confusing?

Comment: I understand how to use it. It was just confusing to me that a delegate is described as an object which accepts methods it can invoke and as an object which wraps a method.

Comment: @FrustratedWithFormsDesigner: Updated my question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There actually *is* this sort of distinction made under the covers. `Delegate` is the single function wrapper, and `MulticastDelegate` is the type that is the composite form of `Delegate`. The confusing part is that `Delegate` isn't really exposed from the innards of the runtime. All delegates created by C# are multicast delegates, even if they only contain a single item.

This is because historically, delegates were largely there to make windows events work nicely, which often would have multiple listeners. Now that delegates are used more for functional programming approaches, it's a little more awkward in theory. In practice, very few people use the multicast functionality outside of events given its downsides (exceptions at any point of the chain will break it, and the caller won't know where, hard to debug) and because it's not exactly common knowledge.

Answer (score 2):

You are right it is a bit confusing.

In the initial .net design, a `Delegate` was supposed to be a 'method reference' to a *single* target method, and a `MulticastDelegate` was supposed to be a container which could contain a variable number of delegates, and invoke them as a batch.

However, before the release of .net 1.0 it was [decided to merge](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/brada/delegate-and-multicastdelegate) the functionality of `Delegate` and `MulticastDelegate`, so that *every* delegate is actually an instance of `MulticastDelegate`, regardless whether it has one or multiple targets. Apparently it was not possible to clean up the API after this change, so we now have a somewhat confusing API.

For example, a delegate has the `Target` property which has a reference to the method to invoke. But in case of a delegate with multiple targets, this property just returns a random one of the targets.

The method `GetInvocationList()` is confusing for the same reason. It is supposed to return an array of all the targets in a delegate. Since there is not a separate type for single-target delegates, it has to return an array of `MulticastDelegate`s, one `MulticastDelegate` for each target. In the case of a single-target delegate it just returns an array with one element which is the original delegate itself.